# Log4j "file:<path>" resolution using spring log4j config listener

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm using spring `Log4jConfigListener`. My `log4j.properties` is on path `C:/bull/dog/log4j.porperties`. I configure `log4jConfigLocation` as
`file:/bull/dog/log4j.properties`. It worked for me on both windows and linux deployments (on linux the file is on `/bull/dog/log4j.properties`)

I made some changes on the project/IDE setup, and it stopped working. On startup, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` (the file is there). I cant seem to figure out whats causing it?

I've tried switching between tomcat versions, default jdk used on my IDE to compile the source. No luck. I'm in the process of debugging `Win32FileSystem` class to see if I find anything but if somebody has any idea or have had this problem before, please throw some insight.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a typo in your description, but you say

- on windows: log4j.porperties
- on linux: log4j.properties

with config set to: log4j.properties

notice **porp** vs. **prop**